# Python - String Manipulation in List Comprehension

Tags: python, string, list

I need to extract the numbers between 2 delimiters ("_dg" and ".csv") in the list of filenames in file00 using Python 3.11.1. The desired result is:

```
['89603','89641']
```

Here is my code:

```
file00 = ['Stats_d2023-07-15_dg89603.csv', 'Stats_d2023-07-15_dg89641.csv']

# getting index of substrings
idx1 = [fn.find("_dg") for fn in file00]
idx2 = [fn.find(".csv") for fn in file00]
 
dgs = [fn[idx1 + len(fn) + 1: idx2] for fn in file00]
```

Here is my console output:

```
>>> file00 = ['Stats_d2023-07-15_dg89603.csv', 'Stats_d2023-07-15_dg89641.csv']
>>>
>>> # getting index of substrings
>>> idx1 = [fn.find("_dg") for fn in file00]
>>> idx2 = [fn.find(".csv") for fn in file00]
>>>
>>> dgs = [fn[idx1 + len(fn) + 1: idx2] for fn in file00]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <listcomp>
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list
>>>
```

I suspect that at least one of my problems is that `idx1` and `idx2` are themselves lists and I am currently erroneously treating them as scalars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correcting your list comprehension this way:

```
dgs = [fn[fn.find("_dg") + len("_dg") : fn.find(".csv")] for fn in file00]
```

outputs the required substrings:

```
['89603', '89641']
```

Answer (score 2):

After these three statements...

```
file00 = ['Stats_d2023-07-15_dg89603.csv', 'Stats_d2023-07-15_dg89641.csv']
idx1 = [fn.find("_dg") for fn in file00]
idx2 = [fn.find(".csv") for fn in file00]
```

You have:

- A list of strings
- A list of start indexes
- A list of end indexes

In order to extract the substrings, you can combine these three lists into a list of (string, start, end) tuples, like this:

```
>>> list(zip(file00, idx1, idx2))
```

Which produces:

```
[('Stats_d2023-07-15_dg89603.csv', 17, 25), ('Stats_d2023-07-15_dg89641.csv', 17, 25)]
```

Given this structure, extracting the numeric substrings is relatively straightforward:

```
>>> [fn[start+len('_dg'):end] for fn,start,end in zip(file00, idx1,idx2)]
['89603', '89641']
```

Answer (score 1):

You might also use regular expressions in your list comprehension.

```
>>> file00 = [
...   'Stats_d2023-07-15_dg89603.csv', 
...   'Stats_d2023-07-15_dg89641.csv'
... ]
>>> import re
>>> r = re.compile(r'(?<=_dg) (\d+) (?=\.csv)', re.X)
>>> [
...   m[0]
...   for x in file00
...   for m in ( r.search(x), )
...   if m
... ]
['89603', '89641']
```

In your code you are attempting to use parallel lists of information. This is rarely the right answer, but if you wanted it to work, you could enumerate your filenames and use that index.

```
>>> file00 = ['Stats_d2023-07-15_dg89603.csv', 'Stats_d2023-07-15_dg89641.csv']
>>> idx1 = [fn.find("_dg") for fn in file00]
>>> idx2 = [fn.find(".csv") for fn in file00]
>>> idx1
[17, 17]
>>> idx2
[25, 25]
>>> [
...   x[ idx1[i] + len('_dg') : idx2[i] ] 
...   for i, x in enumerate(file00)
... ]
['89603', '89641']
```

But ask yourself what happens if the filenames deviate from this format? What if `idx1` and `idx2` are not of the same length?